# jquery load element attribute href

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have the following

```
$('.quickview-dialog-left').load('/productlargetest .productlargeimage a');
```

the href of this a tag is an image. And I want to use that url and add an image inside the quickview-dialog-left but the above only brings in the entire a tag.

How would I bring in the href of the a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.quickview-dialog-left').load('/productlargetest .productlargeimage a');
$('.quickview-dialog-left').html("<img src='"+$('.quickview-dialog-left a').attr("href")+"'/>");
```

Side comment: loading a whole page seems like an overkill to just get an image...